# Paramagnetic Susceptibility of Conduction Electron

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am using the textbook 'Introduction to Solid State Physics' to learn about 'PARAMAGNETIC SUSCEPTIBILITY OF CONDUCTION ELECTRON' (Book by Charles Kittel)

Consider the diagram when a field is applied

> [image: Blockquote]

I dont understand how we can have total energy which is negative. In the case of the 'parallel to field spin', there is section that shows negative total energy

Comment: That textbook title is shared by a whole lot of authors!

Comment: Also, it is just an arbitrary definition of where zero is.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how we can have total energy which is negative. In the case of the 'parallel to field spin', there is section that shows negative total energy

Let us consider an electron in a conduction band with dispersion law $\epsilon_c(\mathbf{k})$. Its energy in magnetic field $B$ is
$$
E_\pm(\mathbf{k})=\epsilon_c(\mathbf{k})\pm \mu B,$$
where the second term is the Zeeman energy, with the sign depending on whether the electron is alinged along or against the field. Now, if for simplicity, we work in the effective mass approximation, i.e.,
$$
\epsilon(\mathbf{k})\approx \epsilon_c(0) + \frac{\hbar^2\mathbf{k}^2}{2m^*},$$
we get the two parabolas shown in the figure in the OP: one with zero at $-\mu B$, and the other with zero at $+\mu B$ in respect to the bottom of the band at $\epsilon_c(0)$.

**Remark:** Of course, in non-relativistic case the choice of the energy origin is arbitrary, so nothing prevents the energy from being negative. My answer answer was an attempt to guess the real question behind the awkward formulation in the OP: `I don't understand how we can have total energy which is negative.`